# How to 2 Oracle Database in 1 Query

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a databases like:

1. Name: A -> Table: B
2. Name: C-> Table: D

I need to combine these tables and select somethings for my grid. But I do not know how to do it.

SELECT should be like:

```
SELECT B.PN, B.PMA_PN, B.APPROVAL_DATE, B.STATUS, D.CHAPTER ...
```

---

PS: Table B and Table D has PN in common but Table D PN comprises Table B PN. Keep that in mind.

Comment: What have you done so far?? At least google it believe that you have [Accessing and Modifying Information in Multiple Databases](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28324/tdpii_distdbs.htm#BABEFFBB)

Comment: @Onur YILMAZ : Please clear your requirement , firstly are your talking about database or shema ? ,if your taking about database ,which database your executing the query.And please read the concept of dblinks

Answer (score 0):

What you should look into is [DB-links](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm).
It enables you to link databases so you can fetch data from multiple dbs in one query.

After the link configuration, you can use the link by typing the table name follow by @ + database name like this:

```
SELECT B.PN, B.PMA_PN, B.APPROVAL_DATE, B.STATUS, D.CHAPTER
FROM Table@dbname1 A, Table@dbname2 B 
WHERE A.PN = B.PN...etc
```

Answer (score -1):

2 Databases are as follows:
Database **A** Table **B**
Database **C** Table **D**

> For grid select query is as follows

```
SELECT B.PN,B.PMA_PN,B.APPROVAL_DATE, B.STATUS,D.CHAPTER
FROM A.B,C.D
WHERE B.PN=D.PN;
```

That's all!!

Comment: The original question is for two different database not 2 schema's in a database